# Why Is My Expanding Image Grid Not Working?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, grid

I apologize in advance if this is just too much to ask but, I'm at my wits end in trying to figure this out.  My biggest issue is that I am nowhere near an adept with JS.  I've done quite a few tutorials to no avail as far my problem goes.  As my previous posts have indicated, I'm attempting to add an expandable image grid to my site but, have run into many issues.  I can only assume that my current attempt is not working due to a JS issue.  I'm not getting the block layout nor our my thumbnails expanding.  Although I could be completely wrong, I think the issue is that my JS is not pointing to the right source, which I'm not 100% sure how to accomplish.  Completely a JS newb.  I don't expect anyone to "do my work for me" but, if you can point me in the right direction, I would certainly appreciate it.

Here is the page where I am attempting to place the image grid:  http://rthhockey.com/coachshop

This is a working example of what I am trying to replicate:  https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ThumbnailGridExpandingPreview/

The code I am using:

```
HTML
<div class="container"> 
            <div class="main">
                <ul id="og-grid" class="og-grid">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" data-largesrc="https://i.imgur.com/qVKUdPN.png" data-title="Azuki bean" data-description="Swiss chard pumpkin bunya nuts maize plantain aubergine napa cabbage soko coriander sweet pepper water spinach winter purslane shallot tigernut lentil beetroot.">
                            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/qVKUdPN.png" alt="img01"/>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" data-largesrc="https://i.imgur.com/qVKUdPN.png" data-title="Veggies sunt bona vobis" data-description="Komatsuna prairie turnip wattle seed artichoke mustard horseradish taro rutabaga ricebean carrot black-eyed pea turnip greens beetroot yarrow watercress kombu.">
                            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/qVKUdPN.png" alt="img02"/>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" data-largesrc="https://i.imgur.com/qVKUdPN.png" data-title="Dandelion horseradish" data-description="Cabbage bamboo shoot broccoli rabe chickpea chard sea lettuce lettuce ricebean artichoke earthnut pea aubergine okra brussels sprout avocado tomato.">
                            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/qVKUdPN.png" alt="img03"/>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" data-largesrc="https://i.imgur.com/qVKUdPN.png" data-title="Azuki bean" data-description="Swiss chard pumpkin bunya nuts maize plantain aubergine napa cabbage soko coriander sweet pepper water spinach winter purslane shallot tigernut lentil beetroot.">
                            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/qVKUdPN.png" alt="img01"/>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" data-largesrc="https://i.imgur.com/qVKUdPN.png" data-title="Veggies sunt bona vobis" data-description="Komatsuna prairie turnip wattle seed artichoke mustard horseradish taro rutabaga ricebean carrot black-eyed pea turnip greens beetroot yarrow watercress kombu.">
                            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/qVKUdPN.png" alt="img02"/>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" data-largesrc="https://i.imgur.com/qVKUdPN.png" data-title="Dandelion horseradish" data-description="Cabbage bamboo shoot broccoli rabe chickpea chard sea lettuce lettuce ricebean artichoke earthnut pea aubergine okra brussels sprout avocado tomato.">
                            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/qVKUdPN.png" alt="img03"/>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" data-largesrc="https://i.imgur.com/qVKUdPN.png" data-title="Azuki bean" data-description="Swiss chard pumpkin bunya nuts maize plantain aubergine napa cabbage soko coriander sweet pepper water spinach winter purslane shallot tigernut lentil beetroot.">
                            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/qVKUdPN.png" alt="img01"/>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" data-largesrc="https://i.imgur.com/qVKUdPN.png" data-title="Veggies sunt bona vobis" data-description="Komatsuna prairie turnip wattle seed artichoke mustard horseradish taro rutabaga ricebean carrot black-eyed pea turnip greens beetroot yarrow watercress kombu.">
                            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/qVKUdPN.png" alt="img02"/>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" data-largesrc="https://i.imgur.com/qVKUdPN.png" data-title="Dandelion horseradish" data-description="Cabbage bamboo shoot broccoli rabe chickpea chard sea lettuce lettuce ricebean artichoke earthnut pea aubergine okra brussels sprout avocado tomato.">
                            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/qVKUdPN.png" alt="img03"/>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

CSS
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/default.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/component.css" />

JS
<script src="js/modernizr.custom.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/grid.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function() {
                Grid.init();
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: Is there a reason you need JS for this? Are the images being fed from an API?

Comment: @hungerstar thanks for your response.  To answer your question honestly, I'm not sure.  I'd prefer not to use JS because, as mentioned above, I'm not real adept with it.  Do you have any suggestions as to how to eliminate it.  My images are coming from URL.  Thanks again for your input and I'll look forward to hearing back from you.

Comment: @hungerstar In a nut shell, I'm just trying to build an expanding image/thumbnail grid in which I can add text to the expanding panel.  If you have any suggestions, I'm all ears.  Thanks.

Comment: Two questions: **1)** when you say expanding grid - is this a dynamic thing? As in from the browser side you click/submit something and images are added/removed? Or does this simply mean you'll add images later on to the grid via HTML? **2)** Kind of the same question but in reference to adding text - is this a dynamic thing or something in the HTML? If you are not looking to add/remove (like filtering images) then you probably do not need JS unless you have a crazy amount of them. Then JS might come in if you wanted to lazy load them for site performance reasons.

Comment: I might have answered a couple of my own questions. You want to be able to click an image, and have a row appear with some info/links/whatever. That expandable row **would** require some JS. Do you have a plugin that you are trying to use with this or is `js/grid.js` your own code?

Comment: @hungerstar I will add the images via HTML.  As far as the text goes, as you may have seen, this is simply a thumbnail image of a hockey drill, when the thumb nail is clicked the panel will expand to show details of the drill.  I'm looking for something similar to Google Images.  There is no need to filter the images.  I'm only looking at approximately 12 images per grid.  Nothing major.  This is where I get caught up.  With the JS.  I thought I could point to the JS "library" somewhere and I'm not sure how to load plugin.  If I can accomplish this without JS, that would be great.

Comment: You'll need JavaScript.

Comment: @hungerstar Again, thanks for taking the time to help me.  Was afraid of that.  In looking at my code above, or even the working example here(https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ThumbnailGridExpandingPreview/), can you at least get me started in figuring out how to install JS or point me somewhere that will make this a little easier.  I have the script files downloaded to my Chromebook.  Just don't know where to go from there or how to install.  I would appreciate it.

Comment: It looks like the tutorial provides everything you need. So it seems to me it migh tbe an issue of properly implementing, i.e. adding all the right CSS classes and HTML attributes in the right places, HTML structure, and ensuring the JS is being loaded on your page. As of right now, your CSS and JS are not being found. Make sure the files exist and that the paths pointing to them are correct.

Comment: @hungerstar Okay.  So, you're saying the JS is functioning correctly?  Essentially, I just copied the code from the downloaded index.html file so, at this point, other than changing the image files, I haven't really changed anything so,CSS should still be structured as it originally was. I have even just grabbed the soure code from https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ThumbnailGridExpandingPreview/ but, it's still not working.

Comment: `grid.js` is still not being loaded. Make sure it is being loaded where you're telling it to. Use your browser's dev tools to find out what is being loading and not. For _Chrome_ press F12 and then click the _Network_ tab, reload page. There will be a number of files that are red that have not loaded. Once you get your files loading correctly things will **probably** work.